# How to place XAML-only resources in a DLL (Reference) file to be used by WPF applications?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

My WPF applications are reaching the level of complexity at which it becomes desirable to place some of the code and other resources inside a Reference file (*.dll).

I am sure I can figure out how to do this, by following the myriad applications out there.

In this particular case, however, the files are two, XAML:

[image]

Can somebody please provide an example on how to **expose** or **publish** the XAML resources? Are *.cs files required?

[image]

TIA

The XAML file outlined by @HighCore should look like this:

```
<Application x:Class="Application"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: That is an excellent question, I second it. A minimal example would be very appreciated.

Comment: @swiss_programmer - You want them to be embed in your dll and want to load at run time?

Comment: Exactly. My problem is that for some reason sometimes the resource is not found. I rebuild a few times, say a little prayer, rub a rabbit's feet, knock on wood, and voila! The resource is found and used. As the application gets more complex is has become impossible to reach the resource, and I figure that my chances will improve by placing the resources in a Reference File.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XAML ResourceDictionaries do not generate classes. I'm not sure why you would expect such thing.

Simply move the needed `ResourceDictionary` definitions to a separate assembly then use the [Pack URI Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) to merge these resources to your application's Resources in `app.xaml`:

```
<Application ....>
   <Application.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml"/> 
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: You are saying that I do not really need to store my stuff inside a *.dll (Reference File), and provided a way to make my XAML contents reachable, correct? (Just to make sure we are in the same page!)

Comment: Is a "separate assembly" a *.dll file?

Comment: HighCore: How about the following project? Would I be wrong if I tried to implement a solution based on this? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W

Comment: @swiss_programmer dude, yes, an assembly is a "dll file". You need to become familiar with .Net terminology.

Comment: "yes, an assembly is a "dll file" So I need to start a new project in Visual Studio, of type "Class Library" and that project will generate the new assembly (aka DLL). Will this assembly end up becoming a Reference File (to be consumed by future applications)?

Comment: @swiss_programmer yes. There's no such thing as a "Reference File" In .Net terminology, so I'm not 100% sure what you're talking about, but I guess you're referring to an assembly reference. In which case yes, you can create an assembly and reference that from other assemblies as needed.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the files that Visual Studio keeps in a folder named "References". I assume that a non-native *.exe file (ie .NET) is also known as an "Assembly"?

Comment: @swiss_programmer yes. .Net code is compiled into units called assemblies. An Exe or .dll file containing .Net IL is an assembly.